# HowTo create deep links with multiple NavHostFragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

The examples I found are either showing a single (nested) navigation graph which will be used for deep linking or they're showing nested navigation with multiple NavHostFragments but do not provide deep linking.

---

I have the following scenario:

**MainActivity**

Has the main-NavHostFragment which handles the main navigation to HomeFragment, PostsFragment, ProfileFragment. home, post**s** and profile should be shown in the bottom navigation.

**PostFragment**

The detail fragment for a post. It will be opened when we tap on a list item in PostsFragment. This layout has a NavHostFragment which handles the sub navigation regarding a post (PostDetailsFragment, PostCommentsFragment)

---

How can I provide deep links to **myapp://post/{postId}/comments** with multiple NavHostFragments?

Best,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need several nav host fragments. Please start looking into this project https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample, in particular these extensions: https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt.

Your activity layout should be similar to this one:

```
    <!-- Fragments Container -->

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout" />

    <!-- Bottom Navigation View -->

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

You can keep your deep links in nested graph of navigation graph mentioned in your manifest. In your nested graph, don't forget to mark your landing fragment with `<deepLink.../>`

Comment: Thanks. But I actually want two navHosts. Because I want to be able to navigate the inner fragment independently of the outter one.

Comment: The idea behind nav graph based links is to reconstruct backstack. In your case, I don't understand how/where to user will be 'backing'. I'd like to know it is even possible - don't think so.

Comment: I thought the outter navHost could be the default one and receive the backpressed events. I also thought I could listen in the outer fragment for back events. While doing so I would check for the inner navigation controller if I either of to popBack the inner controller or popBack the outer one as needed. So my thoughts... :)